# How to submit array to an unmapped form field in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony4, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to submit array with values to a symfony 4 form field but the validation keeps failing.

I'm in the process of updating my application from symfony 2.7 to symfony 4. The problem is that a form that I used to use now always fails validation due to changes in symfony forms.

The symfony form has the following field

```
$builder->add('contactData', null, ['mapped' => false])
```

In symfony 2.7 I would always submit a POST request with array values in the `contactData` field and since it's not mapped it would just set the data to the field object in the submit process and the values were accessed in the Handler. Example request:

```
{
    "name": {
        "aField": "aValue",
        "contactData": {
             "something": "value"
         }
    }
}
```

However in symfony 4 there is now an added validation check in the `\Symfony\Component\Form\Form` class

```
} elseif (\is_array($submittedData) && !$this->config->getCompound() && !$this->config->hasOption('multiple')) {
```

that causes the validation to fail when submiting data to the `contactData` field, since the submittedData is indeed an array. I've been looking all over the internet and reading through the documentation of symfony but I can't seem to find a way to induce the same behavior as in symfony 2.7.

I would much appreciate any advice, I've been stuck on this for a while

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe setting the field as a `CollectionType` could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has changed from v2.7 to 4.0, there is a lot of default values changed;

I faced the same problem and after 2 hours of investigations, 
I ended up adding the attributes `compound` and `allow_extra_field`.

So, this should solve your problem:

```php
$builder->add('contactData', null, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'compound' => true,
    'allow_extra_fields' => true,
])
```

**EDIT**:

This didn't work as expected, I ended up with no error and no content as a submitted data, so I created a new type to add fields dynamically on a pre-submit event as following:

UnstructuredType.php

```php
<?php

namespace ASTechSolutions\Bundle\DynamicFormBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

/**
 * Class UnstructuredType.
 *
 * This class is created to resolve the change of form's behaviour introduced in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/29307
 * From v3.4.21, v4.1.10 and v 4.2.2, Symfony requires defining fields and don't accept arrays on a TextType for ex.
 * TODO: this is a temporary solution and needs refactoring by declaring explicitly what fields we define, and then accept on requests
 *
 */
class UnstructuredType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $this->addChildren($event->getForm(), $event->getData());
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param $data
     */
    public function addChildren(FormInterface $form, $data)
    {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                    $form->add($name);
                } else {
                    $form->add($name, null, [
                        'compound' => true
                    ]);

                    $this->addChildren($form->get($name), $value);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $form->add($data, null, [
                'compound' => false,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need @sym183461's UnstructuredType in the other answer.

The information is in the extra fields.

You define the field like @sym183461 said:

```
$builder->add('contactData', null, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'compound' => true,
    'allow_extra_fields' => true,
])
```

And then you can do this:

```
$contactData = $form->get('contactData')->getExtraFields()
```

All your data is in there, and it works with deep structures just fine.